# Add mysql specific ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC to create table statement generated by jooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, mysql-5.6

I have an application which I need to backport to mysql 5.6.

This application uses rather large composite keys which works fine on mysql 5.7 because innodb-large-prefix is enabled by default.

I can configure mysql 5.6 to use innodb-large-prefix, but it also requires to create tables with `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `COMPRESSED`.

Here is the SQL example I would like to achieve using `jooq`:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain` (
  `path` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index1` (`path`)
) ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

These are the mysql 5.6 documentation for reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom storage clauses to `CREATE TABLE` statements by using the [`CreateTableStorageStep.storage()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/CreateTableStorageStep.html#storage-java.lang.String-) method. E.g.

```
ctx.createTable("domain")
   .column("path", VARCHAR(300).nullable(false))
   .constraint(constraint("index1").unique("path"))
   .storage("ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC")
   .execute();
```

Comment: One can always count on jooq and Lukas. Anyways I guess the documentation is a bit behind of the new feature as I could not find this here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/create-statement/

Your answer seems to me a perfect example to add.